# wix msi install: registry is removed on upgrade if removeexistingproducts is scheduled after installFinalize

Tags: wix, registry

Hi I am trying to get incremental upgrade ( only modified files are updated) meaning I am scheduling removeexistingproducts after installfinalize all goes fine till the end when my registry keys are gone. I am clueless as to what might cause registry to get wiped out? If removeexistingproducts is scheduled before installinitialize then my registry keys are there.

Thank you for your time,

Regards

Konstantin

Answer (score 0):

This can only happen if there is a violation of windows installer component rules.
What might be happening is that, the registry keys are being created in the same place but have different component GUIDs in both of your base as well as the upgraded installer. In such a case, the components are not reference counted correctly and hence, the registry keys are removed when the older product is uninstalled as part of the major upgrade using RemoveExisintProducts.

Do the components which create the registry entries have different component GUID's between both the versions of your installers (i.e base version as well as the upgraded version). If so, you will have to make sure that they have the same component GUID's associated with them.

Open both of your msi packages using  **Orca** and observe the component Guid's for these registry keys. If they are different, make sure to make them consistent in both the packages.

Hope this helps.

There is a really good article which will give you a better understanding of what i have just told.

Take a look at:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/heaths/archive/2010/04/09/major-upgrades-with-shared-components.aspx

Comment: Hey Kiran thank you for taking the time and respond to my question. Guids are same but I added more registry keys into component . If I want to add more registry keys do I need to create additioanl separate component? I tried both ways but it gets deleted in both cases

Comment: Create a verbose windows installer  log file and then search for the component GUID's of the components which are being deleted  to see as to why they are being deleted. This is purely a reference counting issue. If you want to create more registry keys, it depends on what those registry keys are meant for? Are these registry keys associated with other files?If so, associating the registry keys with their associated files makes sense. The best practice to create windows installer components is listed at : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368269(v=vs.85).aspx